# How to send an e-mail from Windows Phone without using EmailComposeTask?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I need my application to send an e-mail to me directly without using the EmailComposeTask.
I also don't want to use a webservice for that.
Is there any open-source framework I could use?

Comment: You should use a web service.  Otherwise, you'll be distributing an email password.

Comment: It's just a question of having a secure connection to the smtp like all e-mail clients.

Comment: What is the email for? If reporting, have you seen [Little Watson](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andypennell/archive/2010/11/01/error-reporting-on-windows-phone-7.aspx)? And the [extended version](http://bjorn.kuiper.nu/2011/10/02/wp7-littlewatson-extended-error-reporting-to-http-endpoint/)

Comment: @andrecarlucci: And that requires a hard-coded password.

Comment: @SLaks Not necessarily hard-coded, but yes, you need a password. Like all e-mail clients. And wouldn't a webservice need authentication anyway? Sorry, I'm not getting your point.

Comment: No a web service does not need authentication (from the phone) @andrecarlucci's concern is putting your password into every app. This would be a bigger security risk than your password in your service

Comment: @ShawnKendrot A web service that sends e-mail without authentication doesn't sound like a good thing to me. Anyway, we are diverting from the subject. I think the answer is: "no, currently there is no framework allowing you to do that". Could someone post this answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently not a way to send email w/o user input unless you want to send some information to a service and have the service send the email